# C++ std::vector iterators error

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, stdvector

First of all **I'm sorry for my bad english**, hope you guys will understand me :) Im writing WinAPI game and my classes behave very strange: all operations with vector
crash my program so Windows says that my .exe stopped working. But when I debug these lines
I get exceptions.

This is how my class header looks like:

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H_INCLUDED
#define FIGURE_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Other.h"

using namespace std;

enum Figure_Type { I, J, L, O, S, T, Z };

class Figure
{
public:
    /* CONSTRUCTORS */
    Figure();
    Figure(Figure_Type);

    /* MOVEMENT */
    bool                Move(vector<Cell>&, Direction&);
    void                Drop(vector<Cell>&);
    bool                Rotate(vector<Cell>&);

    /* OTHER */ 
    void                Draw(HDC&);

private:

    /* METHODS */   
    void                Generate();
    void                GenerateMasks();
    void                GenerateFigure();
    Figure              GetFigureCopy() const;  

    /* DATA */
    Shift               shift;
    char                mask[4][4];
    vector<Cell>        vCells;
    Figure_Type         type;
    int                 rotation;
};

#endif
```

My constructors are using Generate() method, which code is:

```
void Figure::GenerateFigure()
{
    vCells.clear();
    int defPosX = 4,
            defPosY = 20;
    Cell    cell;

    for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            if(mask[y][x] == '0')
            {
                cell.x = defPosX + x + shift.dx;
                cell.y = defPosY - y + shift.dy;
                vCells.push_back(cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting exceptions on vCells.clear() method and (if I comment first line) vCells.push_back(cell) line. Actually every operation with vector / vector iterators crash my program even incrementing iterator, those are just the first so my code isn't running any longer after them.
Exception text:

**"Unhandled exception at 0x5A4ACCD2 (msvcp110d.dll) in Tetris_completely_new.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback."**

And these exceptions are thrown on 217's line of "xutility". I commented it:

```
....
// MEMBER FUNCTIONS FOR _Container_base12
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()
    {   // orphan all iterators
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy != 0)
        {   // proxy allocated, drain it
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

        for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
            *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
            **(*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;**    // <------------ THIS LINE
        _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
        }
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
    }
....
```

Here is how my **Cell struct** looks like:

```
struct Cell
{
    Cell() : x(1), y(1) { }
    Cell(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y) { }

    void Draw(HDC&) const;

    bool operator ==(const Cell& a) const { return (x == a.x && y == a.y); } 
    bool operator !=(const Cell& a) const { return !(*this == a); } 

    int x;
    int y;
};
```

And **Figure constructor**:

```
Figure::Figure()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    vCells.clear();
    type = Figure_Type(rand() % 7);
    rotation = 0;
    shift.dx = 0;
    shift.dy = 0;

    Generate();
}
```

Comment: I would like to have a look at the Cell class memory allocation/deallocation.

Comment: could you please show piece of code which can be used for reproducing your problem

Comment: Your current code looks fine, error is some where else

Comment: You have UB (a memory corruption problem) at some point before the actual crash. They say [App Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) can be used to find such things, I have never tried it.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the posted code. I guess the error is in the `Cell` class. Why not post that class?

Comment: or maybe in one of the Figure constructors.

Comment: or maybe he's calling `->GenerateFigure()` on a null pointer somewhere. If both `Cell` and `Figure::Figure()` look fine, it would be good to see the stack trace.

Comment: Added Cell struct code and Figure's constructor as you guys asked.

Comment: Also I can say that this is the 3rd time Im rewriting this game, but code is the same in general, just tried some stupid ideas to get rid of this errors. And the previous time (when I used list instead of vector) my program was working from time to time. It looked like some kind of magic: I build and get ".exe stoped working", then I build (without changing the code) and it works, sometimes it worked before I used Move method, then the figure tried to redraw and I got exception throwed while incrementing iterator.

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code. You say that constructors use the `Generate` method, but then you provide the code of the `GenerateFigure` method.

Comment: My Generate Method only runs GenerateMasks and GenerateFigure methods. It consist only of these tho lines :)

Answer (score 1):

You're likely invoking undefined behaviour.

Without any more information, I'd say you're calling instance methods through stale object references/pointers (a reference taken at the time of callback registration is no longer valid?).

Also, as currently written in the question, you're generating a figure based on unitialized bytes in `mask`, so you'd likely want to initialize these too.

Here's a take on oa slightly modernized/cleaned up version. Note

- the use of initializer lists
- uniform initialization
- reordered member initialization
- not using `using namespace` in headers
- moved `srand` into `main` instead of the constructor

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/962a77a9533e4faf)

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H_INCLUDED
#define FIGURE_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   include <Windows.h>
#   include "Other.h"
#else
#   include <cstdint>
#   include <cstdlib>
#   include <ctime>

using HDC = uint32_t;
#endif

struct Cell
{
    Cell(int _x=1, int _y=1): x(_x), y(_y) { }

    void Draw(HDC&) const;

    bool operator ==(const Cell& a) const { return (x == a.x && y == a.y); }
    bool operator !=(const Cell& a) const { return !(*this == a); }

    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Shift
{
    Shift(int dx=0, int dy=0) : dx(dx), dy(dy) {}
    int dx, dy;
};

enum class Direction
{
    up, down, left, right
};

enum Figure_Type { I, J, L, O, S, T, Z };

class Figure
{
public:
    /* CONSTRUCTORS */
    Figure();
    Figure(Figure_Type);

    /* MOVEMENT */
    bool        Move(std::vector<Cell>&, Direction&);
    void        Drop(std::vector<Cell>&);
    bool        Rotate(std::vector<Cell>&);

    /* OTHER */
    void        Draw(HDC&);

private:

    /* METHODS */
    void        Generate();
    void        GenerateMasks();
    void        GenerateFigure();
    Figure      GetFigureCopy() const;

    /* DATA */
    char        mask[4][4];
    std::vector<Cell> vCells;
    Figure_Type  type;
    int         rotation;
    Shift       shift;
};

#endif

/*
 * And I'm getting exceptions on vCells.clear() method and (if I comment first
 * line) vCells.push_back(cell) line. Actually every operation with vector /
 * vector iterators crash my program even incrementing iterator, those are just
 * the first so my code isn't running any longer after them.
 *
 * Exception text:
 * **"Unhandled exception at 0x5A4ACCD2 (msvcp110d.dll) in
 *    Tetris_completely_new.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was
 *    encountered during a user callback."**
 *
 * And these exceptions are thrown on 217's line of "xutility". I commented it:
 *
 *   ....
 *   // MEMBER FUNCTIONS FOR _Container_base12
 *   inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()
 *     { // orphan all iterators
 *    #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
 *     if (_Myproxy != 0)
 *       { // proxy allocated, drain it
 *       _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);
 *
 *       for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
 *         *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
 *         **(*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;**    // <------------ THIS LINE
 *       _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
 *       }
 *    #endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
 *     }
 *   ....
 *
 * Here is how my **Cell struct** looks like:
 */

//And **Figure constructor**:

Figure::Figure()
  : mask {{0}},
    vCells(),
    type((Figure_Type) (rand() % 7)),
    rotation(0),
    shift({0,0})
{
    Generate();
}

//My constructors are using Generate() method, which code is:
void Figure::Generate()
{
    GenerateFigure();
}

void Figure::GenerateFigure()
{
    vCells.clear();
    for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            if(mask[y][x] == '0')
                vCells.push_back({4 + x + shift.dx, 20 - y + shift.dy});
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    Figure fig1;
    Figure fig2;
}
```